# Доступ пользователю к базе mysql через CMD

Tags: mysql, cmd

Изучаю mysql, пытаюсь предоставить доступ локальному пользователю к базе данных с помощью следующей команды:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'jim'@'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

В итоге получаю следующее:

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'publications'

Что не так не могу знать, т.к. делаю все по мануалу и ошибки быть просто не может.

Comment: текущий пользователь (которым вы зашли) не имеет прав для раздачи прав (простите за каламбур), сделайте эту операцию от имени пользователя с соответствующими правами

Comment: База создавалась от имени root пользователя. Как узнать какими правами обладает пользователь?

Comment: Если, ещё актуально, то SHOW GRANTS FOR username@localhost;. Подскажите, а вы задавали пароль root пользователя?